# Is there a Relational Algebra software for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, webapps, kde-apps

I am looking for a program that deals with relational algebra on relations and relationships.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of software that fits your description for other platforms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a link to "[relational](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/relational)", which is a GUI-based relational algebra application.  According to the site, it is an "educational tool" so I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for or not.

You should be able to install it by running the following command from a terminal session:

```
sudo apt-get install relational
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) has some capabilities that would be useful to you?  It's a multi-purpose CAS.  If not, here is a [thick report on Relational Algebra](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~pjm/teaching/student_projects/pm105_report.pdf&ei=YfVXUPn7FYWuigLAqYHwDQ&usg=AFQjCNEOSObNrFCPosYn5G_ryD4Gydm4Gg) that I couldn't make heads or tails of---not even to figure out where the software that the author is talking about is available.

Answer (score 2):

The CAS, wxMaxima is very flexible and may be already installed with Ubuntu.